# Checking only String in a textbox

Tags: javascript

I am having a textbox like this

```
input type="text" size="30" maxlength="50" id="name_first">
```

I would like to show an error message if a number occur anywhere in the text box.

Comment: And you have tried what?

Comment: start with <input type="text" onkeydown="myFunction()">

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using jQuery for keypress event:

```
 $('#name_first').keypress(function (e) {
     if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
          return false; //Show error
      }
});
```

May be you can modify for your use

If you want to use regex you can try

```
var r = /\d+/;
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 solution:

```
<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="50" id="name_first" pattern="[A-Za-z]*" title="Only letters allowed">
```

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp